# Button with gradient like tint color for segmented control

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsgradient

I should to reproduce this behavior

[image]

I've tried using NSGradient with a simple linear gradient in order to fill it but it's a poor result. What kind of gradient is it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the button in a `UINavigationBar` or a toolbar?

`UIBarButtonItem` will do that shading on its own, but it tends to live in a toolbar or navbar.

Comment: No no wait. I want to re-create the same gradient in my custom view (basically I'm porting the appearance of this iOS control under Mac OS X Cocoa) and I need to know how to reproduce the same gradient

Comment: Ah. In that case, you may have some success with this: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it might help get you on your way.